# Difference between void setup() and void setup(void)

Tags: programming, c++

As it says in the title. I have been searching but I cant seem to find the answer.

What is the difference between void setup() and void setup(void) as well as void loop() and void loop(void)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely nothing, in modern versions of C and C++. Specifying no arguments is the same as specifying `void`.

In old versions of C a function with no arguments took a single implicit `int` argument or allowed you to specify the arguments on a separate line, but no one uses anything like that nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. This is for the case of the Arduino. But what about other boards like say the Sparkcore? No difference as well?

Comment: It depends on the compiler, not the platform. But most are like this.

Comment: Up to C99, an empty parentheses meant any number of arguments (not just one int). Though obsolete in C99, it is still supported.